# Settings/configuration for Google Closure compiler? - Play framework 2.0.4

Tags: playframework-2.0, google-closure-compiler

So I really like the Google Closure integration in Play Framework 2.0.X. Now I want only some configuration for the google closure compiler ( seeing that it's possible from the official google closure page ).

Is it possible to add custom google closure settings/configuration for google closure compiler in Play 2.0.4.

I know that it should be done in Build.scala, but have no clue of what to add

Say i want SIMPLE compiler settings instead of ADVANCED, how can i do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I realize this is an old question, but maybe this will be helpful to someone. I'm assuming you're using Scala.

Here's what I found after some code diving. Adding the following lines to your project settings in `project/Build.scala` should enable some advanced features:

```
  closureCompilerOptions += "advancedOptimizations",
  closureCompilerOptions += "checkControlStructures",
  closureCompilerOptions += "checkTypes",
  closureCompilerOptions += "checkSymbols"
```

There's also `checkCaja`; these are defined in [play.core.jscompile.JavascriptCompiler](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/jscompile/JavascriptCompiler.scala)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think, you can influence much on Closure configuration, but you could try what is suggested in the [official documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/AssetsGoogleClosureCompiler).

But I've seen some commits go by about Google Closure on the 2.1 branch on Github. That might change in the next Play update.